# List all files in Documents Folder

Tags: objective-c

I need to list all files in Documents folder and get their names...because I don't know the name of the files..then I can't use:

```
  NSString* documentsPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];

 NSString* foofile = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"filename" ];
 BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:foofile];
```

How can I do?

Resuming: I need the name of the .png's files in Documents folder

Comment: It has a very good reference documentation, you should read it and probably come up with a solution.

Answer (score 4):

**NSFileManager Class Reference**

> contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:error: Performs a shallow search of the
>   specified directory and returns the paths of any contained items.
>
> - (NSArray *)contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:(NSString *)path error:(NSError **)error Parameters path The path to the directory whose contents you want to enumerate. error On input, a pointer to an error object. If an
>     error occurs, this pointer is set to an actual error object containing
>     the error information. You may specify nil for this parameter if you
>     do not want the error information. Return Value An array of NSString
>     objects, each of which identifies a file, directory, or symbolic link
>     contained in path. Returns an empty array if the directory exists but
>     has no contents. If an error occurs, this method returns nil and
>     assigns an appropriate error object to the error parameter
>
> Discussion This method performs a shallow search of the directory and
>   therefore does not traverse symbolic links or return the contents of
>   any subdirectories. This method also does not return URLs for the
>   current directory (“.”), parent directory (“..”), or resource forks
>   (files that begin with “._”) but it does return other hidden files
>   (files that begin with a period character). If you need to perform a
>   deep enumeration, use the
>   enumeratorAtURL:includingPropertiesForKeys:options:errorHandler:
>   method instead.
>
> The order of the files in the returned array is undefined.
>
> Availability Available in iOS 2.0 and later.

That should fulfill your needs